# How to add new login for Microsoft SQL Server for all domain users

Tags: sql, login

I would like to add MYDOMIAN\domain_users as new login in MS SQL 2012. So I create new login, choose mMYDOMAIN as localization but here I don't have option to add 
  all domain users, I can only choose every domain user separately.

Comment: You should be able to add the Domain Users group.  Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I don't have such option I can add:  Users MYDOMAIN/Builtin,  or Authenticated users (but not from MYDOMAIN folder) that'all.

Comment: In the select users dialog you may have to go into "Object Types" and tick the box next to "Groups".

Comment: Yes, after checked Groups in Object Types, I can add Domain users to SQL Logins. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

So anybody and everybody in your Domain can log into this database?

Why?

The vast majority of **Users** don't know one end of a "Select" statement from the other and, quite honestly, shouldn't be let *anywhere near* a database.

I suspect you have to add Users individually because that's the level at which you can grant them permissions.  You don't want to try to grant update permissions to "one" User, only to find that SQL Server's applied them to everybody!

Comment: *Why* is a reasonable frame-challenge question, but if you are using Windows Authentication you can in fact add a group as a login in SQL Server.  The users still get individual identities within SQL, but you don't have to explicitly give them access one by one.

Comment: I need to setup Single Sing On on my SQL based application, but this need to add every authenticated domain user to have login into database. And I don't want to create separately over 300 logins.